# How to get input separated by spaces

Tags: c#

I want to try and get a line of numbers and count them and store them in an array. I want to have the user input numbers up to 100 and I want the program to be able to separate them by spaces and count them in C#

Example: 98 92 86 92 100 92 93

The spaces will be the only separator and it would count 7 grades and store them in an array but I'm not sure how to to really do this.

Comment: this is a real response:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070113/read-numbers-from-the-console-given-in-a-single-line-separated-by-a-space

Answer (score 2):

Not to get empty entries in case of 2 spaces

```
var ints = input.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                     .Select(i => int.Parse(i))
                     .ToList(); //or ToArray() whichever you want
```

Comment: i think the user wants an array.

Comment: @JohnWoo list can be converted to array with a simple method. Should we spoon feed that much?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want an `Array` on this, use `Split` function.

```
string x = "98 92 86 92 100 92 93";
string[] val = x.Split(' ');
int totalCount = val.Length;
```

or a better way to do this is by using `LINQ` which automatically converts into array of integers

```
string x = "98 92 86 92 100 92 93";
int[] y = x.Split(' ').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray();
int totalCount = y.Length;
```